# Return to academia [in administration] from industry

Tags: job-search, administration

A colleague of mine was a very successful, well funded, highly published post-doc at a top-20 university who abdicated her post for industry. Having grown tired of industry, she now toys with the idea of returning to academia, but dreams of a role in administration (higher level, as [associate/assistant][dean/director of x]). She believes that her experience in industry, coupled with strong academic history, may make her a strong candidate. Yet there are few specific examples I can find of academic-turned-industry-turned-administrator.

Specific questions:

1. What is the distribution of administrator posts awarded to pure academics (e.g., step-ups from PI/professor) vs individuals already in administrator roles?
2. What is the distribution of administrator posts made internally vs external hire?
3. Anecdotes of industry-to-academic administrator success stories greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not know any of these answers, but I thought it's worth mentioning that some institutions have "Professor of the Practice" positions that seem to be targeted at people like your colleague (except for the administration part).

Answer (score 1):

In my limited experience, high-level administrator posts filled by current-or-former academics fall under one of the following categories:

- Ex-officio with being a Full Professor somewhere (with perhaps some rotation among Professors)
- Carried out by regular Full Professors on temporary leave from their academic duties, or in parallel with a much-reduced regular academic workload.
- Carried out by Professors Emeritus, or people who academically-retire early from their position as Full Professor to do only managerial work
- Populated only by people who have a special long-standing relation with the academic institution (and aren't Full Professors).

I have encountered a few exceptions to the above, but those were extremely rare.